# react-hook-form: Type 'Control<ICustom, object>' is not assignable to type 'Control<FieldValues, any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I created custom component which extends Controller from react-hook-form and TextField from MUI. Here how i declare my component.

```js
import TextField, * as MUITextFieldProps from "@mui/material/TextField"
import { Controller, ControllerProps } from "react-hook-form"

function Input (props: ControllerProps & MUITextFieldProps.TextFieldProps) {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={props.name}
      control={props.control}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <TextField
          {...props}
          {...field}
        />
      )}
    />
  )
}

export default Input
```

Then when I call it with this snippet

```js
import Button from "@mui/material/Button"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"

import { Input } from "@/components/Input"

interface IOtp {
  otp: string
}

function OtpPage () {
  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm<IOtp>({
    defaultValues: {
      otp: ""
    }
  })

  function onSubmit (data:IOtp) {
    console.log(data)
    alert("Selamat Datang!")
  }
  return (
    <form
      className="flex flex-col items-center gap-8 w-full"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
    >
      <Input
        name="otp"
        control={control}
        label="Kode OTP"
        fullWidth
      />
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        fullWidth
        type="submit"
      >
        Kirim
      </Button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default OtpPage
```

It seems that my custom interface, which is IOtp doesn't match with FieldValues from react-hook-form. I think it's not good enough to remove my custom interface. Any solution for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. I changed my way by not creating it as reusable component. But, maybe it can solved by applied this `props: ControllerProps & Partial<MUITextFieldProps.TextFieldProps>`. I've not try again.